# Make a Valentine wish with your favourite language

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art

Write the most creative program to display your Valentine wish to your favorite programming language, in that language.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;

say "I love Perl";
```

Comment: Accepted @ugoren

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### C/Python Polyglot/Polygamist

Monogamy isn't for everyone.
Based on my answer to [Execute Prints Backwards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20654/3544).

```
#define def main(){0?
#define print printf(
#define return 0)));}

def main():
    print "Python",
    print ", I love you much more than ",
    print "C",
    return

main();
```

Output, when run as C:

```
C, I love you much more than Python
```

Output, when run as Python:

```
Python , I love you much more than  C
```

Comment: This is freaking brilliant.

Answer (score 26):

## JavaScript (ES6)

Pretty version:

```js
           r=/c/g         ,n='\n'
       ,m=/.\d+/g,[,    ,'ca','8b',5,
     'a10b',6,'ca3b',  13,'a4b',1,3,'c'
    ,'a1b',16,'a2b1',5,'cb35cb',35,'ca',
    ,'1b7 JS b',22,'ca2b',31,'ca3b',29,
     ,'ca',5,'b',25,'ca7b',2,1,'ca',9,
      ,'b','17ca',11,'b13ca',14,'b',
       '7c','a1',7,'b1c'].join('').
         replace(m, c=>(c[0]!='a'?
           '\u2665':' ').repeat
              (+c.substr(1))).
                 replace(r,
                     n);
```

Console output:

```
            ♥♥♥♥♥          ♥♥♥♥♥♥
       ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥    ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
     ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
    ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
    ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
     ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥ JS ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
      ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
       ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
         ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
           ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
             ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
               ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
                  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
                     ♥
```

Annotated version:

```js
[
  // Contains the instruction to draw the heart.
  //   * `a` is a space
  //   * `b` is a heart
  //   * `c` is a line break
  // 
  // `a` and `b` instructions are followed by an integer
  // telling how many times the character should be printed.
  // 
  // Abuse JS arrays to split the string in smaller parts.
  ,,'ca','8b',5,'a10b',6,'ca3b',13,'4b13ca1b16a2b1cb35cb35ca1b7'
  // This is the text we want to display.
  ,' JS '
  // Other instructions to draw the heart.
  // This part isn't splitted for readability purpose.
  ,'bca2bca3b29ca5b25ca7b21ca9b17ca11b13ca14b7ca17b1c'
]
// Join every substring.
.join('')
// Process instructions.
.replace(
  // Match all `a` and `b` instructions.
  /.\d+/g,
  c => (
    // Fetch the right character.
    c[0] != 'a'
      ? '\u2665' // `b` Heart
      : ' '      // `a` Space
  )
  // Repeat the character.
  .repeat(
    // Extract the number from the instruction.
    +c.substr(1)
  )
)
// Replace `c` by a line break.
.replace(/c/g,'\n');
```

Answer (score 14):

### Processing

```java
public static final int px = 25;
public static final int rectRad = 3;
PFont font;

public boolean[][] used;
public int[] heart = {
               65, 66, 67,                 72, 73, 74,
           84, 85, 86, 87, 88,         91, 92, 93, 94, 95,
      103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,
  122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,
  142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,
  162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,
      183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,
          204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,
          224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,
              245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,
                  266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,
                      287,288,289,290,291,292,
                          308,309,310,311,
                              329,330
                                 };
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  background(255);
  stroke(127+64);
  strokeWeight(1.75);
  //font=loadFont("Font1.vlw");
  font=createFont("Purisa",28);
  textFont(font,28);
  frameRate(50);
  used = new boolean[width/px][height/px]; // initialised to false by default
}

void draw() {
  int i, j;
  int drawingframes = width * height / px / px;
  int textframesdelay = (int)(500 * frameRate / 1000);
  do {
    i=(int)random(0, width / px);
    j=(int)random(0, height / px);
  } while(used[i][j] && frameCount <= drawingframes);
  used[i][j] = true;
  if(frameCount > drawingframes + textframesdelay) {
    noLoop();
    return;
  } else if(frameCount == drawingframes + textframesdelay) {
    fill(63 + 32);
    text("Dear Processing,", 10, 50);
    text("Happy Valentine's Day!", 80, 200);
    text("Love,\nAce", 10, 430);
    return;
  } else if(frameCount > drawingframes) {
      return; // effectively creating a small delay after drawing the tiles
              // and before writing the text
  }
  int R = (int)random(64, 255 - 64);
  int G = (int)random(128, 255);
  int B = (int)random(128, 255);
  int alpha = (int)random(55, 85);
  int hash = j * width / px + i;
  if(java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(heart,hash)>=0) {
  //if(heart.indexOf(hash) >= 0) {
    R = (int)random(128 + 64, 255);
    G = (int)random(0, 63);
    B = (int)random(0, 63);
    alpha = (int)random(70, 100);
  }
  fill(R, G, B, alpha);
  rect(i * px, j * px, px, px, rectRad, rectRad, rectRad, rectRad);
}
```

See it run online [here](https://adrianiainlam.github.io/valentine/).

Screenshot of one possible output:
[image]

Comment: Nice one. I enjoyed it.

Answer (score 8):

## Befunge 98

```
"/\ "7k:a"/ ":"\ "6k:a"/ "2k:"\ "5k:a"/ ":"89 ":"\ "4k:a"/ "6k:"\ "3k:a"| ":"egnufeB | "2k:a"| "8k:"| "2k:a"\ /____\ / "3k:a'_' 5k:'_\4k:a"?enitnelaV ym eb uoy lliW"aa >:!2+j4,<@
```

Output (as image, because it looks nicer in the console than here):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## PHP

Why overcomplicate, when you can do simplest thing that works?

Program:

```
I ♥ PHP!
```

Output:

```
I ♥ PHP!
```

Comment: It's not about the shortest code - it's about the most creative and beautiful one.

Answer (score 3):

**BASH**

What is better than to SSH to your wifeys/husbands machine and then let her NIC do the fun part of flashing morse code for "Happy Valentines Day" for your favourite scripting language I am sure you've nearly all started with - BASH? And as we Geeks all know - you should *always* have an eye on your machine's NIC ;)

```
#!/bin/bash

#.... .- .--. .--. -.-- ...- .- .-.. . -. - .. -. . ... -.. .- -.--
#1111 12 1221 1221 2122 1112 12 1211 1 21 2 11 21 1 111 211 12 2122

while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do
    ethtool eth0 p$char
done < morse
```

Of course "morse" contains the morse code "translated" to numbers:

> 111131231221312213212231112312312113132132311321313111321131232122

'1' is short, '2' is long and '3' is space. Obviously the obligatory 'ethtool' should be installed. If not, then do your spouse the favour of doing so.

Answer (score 3):

## BASIC

Just because we all wrote one of these once, and this is really the only style that truly expresses this language's simple honest heart.

```basic
10 PRINT "HAPPY VALENTINES DAY BASIC"
20 GOTO 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica

```
ContourPlot3D[(2 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 - (1/10) x^2 z^3 - y^2 z^3 == 
  0, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, Mesh -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8, Red]]
```

[image]

That's [Taubin's heart surface](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taubin%27s%20heart%20surface). Yes, I realize the challenge asks for ASCII art. However, if you're going to downvote it, don't do so because it's excessively beautiful, do it because I stole the code from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12098/drawing-heart-in-mathematica

Answer (score 2):

## [~-~!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/~-~!)

Just for the sake of interest, the character count is **865**.

```
'=~~~~:''=<<'+~>,'+~~~>,':'''=<'+~>,<',<'+~>-~>:''''=<'+~>,<<',~~>+~>+~~:'''''=',',~~:''''''=',<<'+~>,<'+~~>+~>:'''''''=',~~+~~:
@''''':@''':@''':@''':@''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''':@''':@''':@''':@''''''':
@'''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@'':@''''':@'''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@'':@''''''':
@'''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@'''''':@''''''':
@'':@''''':@|I|:@''''':@|<|:@|3|:@''''':@|~|:@|-|:@|~|:@|!|:@''''':@'''':@''''''':
@''''':@'':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@'''':@''''''':
@''''':@''''':@'':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@'''':@''''''':
@''''':@''''':@''''':@'':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@'''':@''''''':
@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@'':@''''':@''''':@''''':@'''':@''''''':
@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@''''':@'':@''''':@'''':@''''''':
```

Output:

```
 ____   ____
/    \ /    \
|           |
\ I <3 ~-~! /
 \         /
  \       /
   \     /
    \   /
     \ /
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python

Remember when people didn't have computers for Valentines and had to etch their lovelife on trees? That's what I'm doing:

```
def valentine(person1,person2):
    leading_whitespace = range(0,4)[::-1] +[0]+range(0,8)
    inside = [3,5,14,14]+range(0,15)[::-1][::2]
    layers = ["  ___    ___",r" /   \  /   \ ",r'/     \/     \ ','|             |']
    for i in range(5,12):
        layers.append(' ' * leading_whitespace[i] + '\\' + ' ' * inside[i] + '/')
    #inserts person1 into layers[4]
    temp = []
    for char in layers[3]: temp.append(char)
    temp[1:len(person1)+1] = person1
    layers[3] = ''.join(temp)

    temp = []
    layers[4] = '|      +     |'

    # do that again for person2
    for char in layers[5]: temp.append(char)
    temp[-len(person2)-1:-1] = person2
    layers[5] = ''.join(temp)

    print '\n'.join(layers)

valentine('Me','Python')
```

Note: the first values of the `inside` variable are hard-coded.
Output:

```
  ___    ___
 /   \  /   \ 
/     \/     \ 
|Me           |
|      +     |
 \    Python/
  \        /
   \      /
    \    /
     \  /
      \/
```

Comment: But the code doesn't use any trees.

Answer (score -3):

mhm is it something like this ?

`<?echo "I love PHP";`

Comment: It's a popularity contest - get creative.

Answer (score -3):

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main();
{
  int i, n;
   printf(" enter n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
          printf(" i love you honey ");
      }  
         scanf("%d",&i);
        getch();
}
```