# Cardinals and ordinals, 1 to 100

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity

Here's a simple one to stretch your compression muscles. Your code (a complete program) must output the spelled-out English representation of all the cardinal numbers from 1 to 100, and then all the ordinal numbers from 1 to 100. The numerals in each list should be delimited by commas and spaces and properly hyphenated. Each list should begin with a single capital letter and conclude with a period. The two lists should be separated by a newline.

For clarity's sake, you must produce this exact byte stream:

```
One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, nineteen, twenty, twenty-one, twenty-two, twenty-three, twenty-four, twenty-five, twenty-six, twenty-seven, twenty-eight, twenty-nine, thirty, thirty-one, thirty-two, thirty-three, thirty-four, thirty-five, thirty-six, thirty-seven, thirty-eight, thirty-nine, forty, forty-one, forty-two, forty-three, forty-four, forty-five, forty-six, forty-seven, forty-eight, forty-nine, fifty, fifty-one, fifty-two, fifty-three, fifty-four, fifty-five, fifty-six, fifty-seven, fifty-eight, fifty-nine, sixty, sixty-one, sixty-two, sixty-three, sixty-four, sixty-five, sixty-six, sixty-seven, sixty-eight, sixty-nine, seventy, seventy-one, seventy-two, seventy-three, seventy-four, seventy-five, seventy-six, seventy-seven, seventy-eight, seventy-nine, eighty, eighty-one, eighty-two, eighty-three, eighty-four, eighty-five, eighty-six, eighty-seven, eighty-eight, eighty-nine, ninety, ninety-one, ninety-two, ninety-three, ninety-four, ninety-five, ninety-six, ninety-seven, ninety-eight, ninety-nine, one hundred.
First, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth, eleventh, twelfth, thirteenth, fourteenth, fifteenth, sixteenth, seventeenth, eighteenth, nineteenth, twentieth, twenty-first, twenty-second, twenty-third, twenty-fourth, twenty-fifth, twenty-sixth, twenty-seventh, twenty-eighth, twenty-ninth, thirtieth, thirty-first, thirty-second, thirty-third, thirty-fourth, thirty-fifth, thirty-sixth, thirty-seventh, thirty-eighth, thirty-ninth, fortieth, forty-first, forty-second, forty-third, forty-fourth, forty-fifth, forty-sixth, forty-seventh, forty-eighth, forty-ninth, fiftieth, fifty-first, fifty-second, fifty-third, fifty-fourth, fifty-fifth, fifty-sixth, fifty-seventh, fifty-eighth, fifty-ninth, sixtieth, sixty-first, sixty-second, sixty-third, sixty-fourth, sixty-fifth, sixty-sixth, sixty-seventh, sixty-eighth, sixty-ninth, seventieth, seventy-first, seventy-second, seventy-third, seventy-fourth, seventy-fifth, seventy-sixth, seventy-seventh, seventy-eighth, seventy-ninth, eightieth, eighty-first, eighty-second, eighty-third, eighty-fourth, eighty-fifth, eighty-sixth, eighty-seventh, eighty-eighth, eighty-ninth, ninetieth, ninety-first, ninety-second, ninety-third, ninety-fourth, ninety-fifth, ninety-sixth, ninety-seventh, ninety-eighth, ninety-ninth, one hundredth.
```

This is code golf, shortest answer in bytes wins.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Common Lisp, <del>88</del> <del>82</del> 80 bytes

```
(format t"~@(~{~R~^, ~}~).
~:*~@(~{~:R~^, ~}~)."(loop as i to 99 collect(1+ i)))
```

(It is part of the language, I hope you don't mind)

#### Output

```
One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, nineteen, twenty, twenty-one, twenty-two, twenty-three, twenty-four, twenty-five, twenty-six, twenty-seven, twenty-eight, twenty-nine, thirty, thirty-one, thirty-two, thirty-three, thirty-four, thirty-five, thirty-six, thirty-seven, thirty-eight, thirty-nine, forty, forty-one, forty-two, forty-three, forty-four, forty-five, forty-six, forty-seven, forty-eight, forty-nine, fifty, fifty-one, fifty-two, fifty-three, fifty-four, fifty-five, fifty-six, fifty-seven, fifty-eight, fifty-nine, sixty, sixty-one, sixty-two, sixty-three, sixty-four, sixty-five, sixty-six, sixty-seven, sixty-eight, sixty-nine, seventy, seventy-one, seventy-two, seventy-three, seventy-four, seventy-five, seventy-six, seventy-seven, seventy-eight, seventy-nine, eighty, eighty-one, eighty-two, eighty-three, eighty-four, eighty-five, eighty-six, eighty-seven, eighty-eight, eighty-nine, ninety, ninety-one, ninety-two, ninety-three, ninety-four, ninety-five, ninety-six, ninety-seven, ninety-eight, ninety-nine, one hundred.
First, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth, eleventh, twelfth, thirteenth, fourteenth, fifteenth, sixteenth, seventeenth, eighteenth, nineteenth, twentieth, twenty-first, twenty-second, twenty-third, twenty-fourth, twenty-fifth, twenty-sixth, twenty-seventh, twenty-eighth, twenty-ninth, thirtieth, thirty-first, thirty-second, thirty-third, thirty-fourth, thirty-fifth, thirty-sixth, thirty-seventh, thirty-eighth, thirty-ninth, fortieth, forty-first, forty-second, forty-third, forty-fourth, forty-fifth, forty-sixth, forty-seventh, forty-eighth, forty-ninth, fiftieth, fifty-first, fifty-second, fifty-third, fifty-fourth, fifty-fifth, fifty-sixth, fifty-seventh, fifty-eighth, fifty-ninth, sixtieth, sixty-first, sixty-second, sixty-third, sixty-fourth, sixty-fifth, sixty-sixth, sixty-seventh, sixty-eighth, sixty-ninth, seventieth, seventy-first, seventy-second, seventy-third, seventy-fourth, seventy-fifth, seventy-sixth, seventy-seventh, seventy-eighth, seventy-ninth, eightieth, eighty-first, eighty-second, eighty-third, eighty-fourth, eighty-fifth, eighty-sixth, eighty-seventh, eighty-eighth, eighty-ninth, ninetieth, ninety-first, ninety-second, ninety-third, ninety-fourth, ninety-fifth, ninety-sixth, ninety-seventh, ninety-eighth, ninety-ninth, one hundredth.
```

#### Explanations

See [Formatted Output to Character Streams](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node200.html).

- `(format t "<control string>" <arguments>)` formats the control string according to the (variadic) arguments and prints to standard output (because `t`)
- `(loop ...)` builds the list of integers from 1 to 100
- `~@( ... ~)` capitalizes the string returned by the inner control string
- `~{ ... ~}` iterates over the current argument and applies the inner formatting to each element
- Inside the iteration, everything that follows `~^` is *not* printed on the last iteration: this is used to add the comma-space separator *between* elements.
- `~R` outputs current argument as a cardinal
- `~:R` outputs current argument as an ordinal
- `~%` outputs a new line
- `~:*` reset the *current* argument to be processed as the previous one, which is used here to reuse the list of integers a second time.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to PrzemysławP.

Comment: And I thought my 340-byte answer was impressive...

Comment: Your rep at this moment is pretty 1337! :D So, unfortunately, I cannot upvote this solution... :(

Comment: @Numeri You can upvote now.  ;)

Comment: Solutions shorted than the kolomogorov complexity of the input are always very impressive! Well done.

Comment: @DLosc It was just to good for me to break... :D

Comment: Two bytes can be saved if you change `~%` to <enter> and `for` to `as`.

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, <s>366</s> <s>342</s> 340 bytes

```
Lcbdj=Y", "++rhJy"one two three four five six seven eight nine"3+tJ+y"ten eleven twelve"+=Nm+d"teen"=by"thir four fif six seven eigh nine"sm+dm++d\-kJKy"twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety"+=H"one hundred"\.jY+rh=J++y"first second third"m+d=T"th"tPby"ninth"3+++tJy"tenth eleventh twelfth"+m+dTNsm++Pd"ieth"m++d\-kJK+H"th."
```

[Live demo.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Lcbdj%3DY"%2C+"%2B%2BrhJy"one+two+three+four+five+six+seven+eight+nine"3%2BtJ%2By"ten+eleven+twelve"%2B%3DNm%2Bd"teen"%3Dby"thir+four+fif+six+seven+eigh+nine"sm%2Bdm%2B%2Bd%5C-kJKy"twenty+thirty+forty+fifty+sixty+seventy+eighty+ninety"%2B%3DH"one+hundred"%5C.jY%2Brh%3DJ%2B%2By"first+second+third"m%2Bd%3DT"th"tPby"ninth"3%2B%2B%2BtJy"tenth+eleventh+twelfth"%2Bm%2BdTNsm%2B%2BPd"ieth"m%2B%2Bd%5C-kJK%2BH"th."&debug=1)

### 342-byte version:

```
Lcbdj", "++rhJy"one two three four five six seven eight nine"3+tJ+y"ten eleven twelve"+=Nm+d"teen"=by"thir four fif six seven eigh nine"sm+dm++d\-kJKy"twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety"+=H"one hundred"\.j", "+rh=J++y"first second third"m+d"th"tPby"ninth"3+++tJy"tenth eleventh twelfth"+m+d"th"Nsm++Pd"ieth"m++d\-kJK+H"th."
```

### 366-byte version:

```
Lcbd
j", "++"One"+tJy"one two three four five six seven eight nine"+y"ten eleven twelve"+=Nm+d"teen"y"thir four fif six seven eigh nine"sm+dm++d\-kJKy"twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety"+=H"one hundred"\.
j", "+"First"+++t=Jy"first second third fourth fifth sixth seventh eighth ninth"y"tenth eleventh twelfth"+m+d"th"Nsm++Pd"ieth"m++d\-kJK+H"th."
```

Answer (score 6):

## PHP - 491 bytes

Small cheat here for the cardinals (I'm using the NumberFormatter class that comes default with PHP):

```
echo'One, ';$x=new NumberFormatter(0,5);for($i=1;$i++<100;)echo$x->format($i).($i>99?
'.':', ');echo"
";$y=[First,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth,tenth,
eleventh,twelfth,thirteenth,fourteenth,fifteenth,sixteenth,seventeenth,eighteenth,nineteenth,
twentieth];for($z=[thirtieth,fortieth,fiftieth,sixtieth,seventieth,eightieth,ninetieth];
$j++<99;$q=floor($j/10),$w=$z[$q-2])echo$j<21?$y[$j-1]:($j%10?$x->format($q*10).'-'.
strtolower($y[$j%10-1]):$w),', ';echo'one hundredth.';
```

(added a few new lines for readability)

Comment: Warnings are generally allowed, remove all the `@` (-4 bytes). Use a newline instead of writing `\n` (-1 byte). Put the definition of `$z` into the initialisation of the second `for` loop (-1 byte).

Comment: Save 6 bytes by using the procedural method instead of the object-oriented constructor

Answer (score 6):

### PHP 5.3+, 195 bytes

That includes the newline character.

It's part of the [`NumberFormatter`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class, just like [razvan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57058/22867). Except I spell out both the cardinals and ordinals according to the ICU.

```php
$f=numfmt_create(en,5);$g=clone$f;$g->setTextAttribute(6,'%spellout-ordinal');for($x=$y='',$i=1;$i++<100;){$x.=$f->format($i).($z=$i<=99?', ':'');$y.=$g->format($i).$z;}echo"One, $x.
First, $y.";
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19411974/404623

Comment: Nice! I had no idea of the %spellout-ordinal format.

Answer (score 4):

## Oracle SQL 231 bytes

**[SqlFiddleLiveDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/5737/0)**

```
 SELECT 'O'||SUBSTR(LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(level,'j'),'jsp'),', ')WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY level),2)||'.','F'||SUBSTR(LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(level,'j'),'jTHSP'),', ')WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY level),2)||'.' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY level<101
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>562</s> 464 bytes

Not even done golfing yet!

```
n=>(f=(a,b)=>Array(89).fill(a=btoa(a+`·§·,í*íË7èº»rÍø·,ìrÎÇ¯z{rÍè Ü³)Þ·,ó`).split`z`).map((l,i)=>i<1?b:i<20?a[i]:a[18+(i-i%10)/10]+'-'+a[i%10]).join`, `+', one hundred')(`¢w³·
3¶Þ{7èº¼ß÷³²,s±ëÞ7¢s)ÞÎ×§Íé^½éó·¥½ìí*íyéó~«µç§Íøµç§ÎÈ±µç§ÎÇ¯z{^z|Þmyéó)Þµç§ÎÜÜ³¶«·,ß¢êíË7â~Ü³²,mË;½éíË7¢rÎx§µì³`,'One')+`
`+f(`~*ì·;rÝÎØb­Üß¢êí7â~Øs²,m;½éí7¢Øs)Þ¶íz{aÍé^½éí;pz[Þ¶í*íyéí7èº»^z{aÍøµç§¶ì^z{aÎÇ¯z{^z{aÍè ×Øs)Þµç§¶ó`,'First')+'th'
```

**If this doesn't work I might need to add a hexdump because of all the special characters** Please let me know if this is the case and I'll get to you by tomorrow.

If they are any typos also let me know.

[Code in pastebin (Tested on Safari Nightly)](http://pastebin.com/aFpaszEz)

## Explanation

This may look like a bunch of garbled characters but it's actually pretty simple.

We start by generating the cardinals. This array is compressed using the `btoa` function.

```
['one', ..., 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty', 'thirty', ...,'ninety']
```

To loop through a "range" we use the following:

Now we generate an Array of length 89 using. The `...` is what uncompresses the array

```
Array(89).fill(...)
```

Then map through it, i is the index:

```
.map((l,i)=>
```

Now for the condition, `i < 1` or if it is the first item, we will use a capitalized version of one / first

```
i<1?b
```

Otherwise... if it is less than 20, we output eleven...nineteen

```
i<20?a[i]:
```

Otherwise... using `(i-i%10)/10` we get the last digit of the number. We add 18 to it to compensate for 1..19. We add a `-` and then add the last digit, or i%10

Finally, we add 'one hundred' to the very end because we don't.

We repeat this for both types of numbers and separate with a newline

Comment: Tried with FireFox: the posted code is flawed. The code in pastebin is ok, but misses a period after the first `hundred`. Overall: great job| +1

Comment: What's with the special characters?

Answer (score 3):

## C++ <s>704</s> <s>642</s> <s>620</s> 602

No library usage other than `ostream` `operator<<()` for `char*`s.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
char*q,a[]="|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|ni&u$Il%*twel&bthirte$Q(P#tif#j)/#k'L#|)y#r*4#s'9rst&>cond*5d)zh)gh)U#V)Ch)2h(}#V09$m0M$I0]'g0k)B0|*I#}1A+4$01f+y1u$$|+/nty+(y*`#X*3y)p#V)Ly))y(dyC5~hundred)Oie1o#|1c#}*E#s*a#t*}$&+9#|+T#|+uth",b[448],*s=a,*t=b;int i,j,k;auto p(int k){for(s=b;k--;)while(*s++);return s;}int main(){for(;k=*s++;)if(k>98)*t++=k<'|'?k:" "[k<'~'];else for(i=(k-35)*95+*s++-32,q=t-i/9,k=3+i%9;k--;)*t++=*q++;for(j=0;j<2;++j)for(i=1;b[1+126*j]^=32*(i<3),k=i<20?i:i%10,i<101;++i)std::cout<<p(40+!k*j*11+i/10)<<"-"[!k|i<20]<<p(j*20+k)<<", \0.\n"+i/100*3;}
```

[Live version](http://ideone.com/64xnDc).

With some whitespace and some comments:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Encoded as literal characters or offset/length pairs for previous runs of characters, LZ like
char *q, a[] =
             "|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|ni&u$Il%*twel&bthirte$Q(P#tif#j)/"
             "#k'L#|)y#r*4#s'9rst&>cond*5d)zh)gh)U#V)Ch)2h(}#V09$m0M$I0]'g0k)B0|*I#}1A+4$01f+y1u$$|"
             "+/nty+(y*`#X*3y)p#V)Ly))y(dyC5~hundred)Oie1o#|1c#}*E#s*a#t*}$&+9#|+T#|+uth",
         b[448], *s = a, *t = b;

int i, j, k;

// Find the kth null separated string in array b
auto p(int k) {
    for (s = b; k--;)
        while (*s++)
            ;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    // Decode the compressed 'primitives' we use to build up the output.
    for (; k = *s++;)
        if (k > 98)
            *t++ = k < '|' ? k : " "[k < '~'];
        else
            for (i = (k - 35) * 95 + *s++ - 32, q = t - i / 9, k = 3 + i % 9; k--;) *t++ = *q++;

    // Loop twice over numbers 1-100, building up output from the 'primitives' in our array
    for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        for (i = 1; b[1 + 126 * j] ^= 32 * (i < 3), k = i < 20 ? i : i % 10, i < 101; ++i)
            std::cout << p(40 + !k * j * 11 + i / 10) << "-"[!k | i < 20] << p(j * 20 + k)
                      << ", \0.\n" + i / 100 * 3;
}
```

The compressed string is decoded from `a` into `b`:

```
|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|
sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen||first|second|third|fourth|fifth|sixth|seventh|eighth|
ninth|tenth|eleventh|twelfth|thirteenth|fourteenth|fifteenth|sixteenth|seventeenth|
eighteenth|nineteenth|||twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety|one~
hundred|||twentieth|thirtieth|fourtieth|fiftieth|sixtieth|seventieth|eightieth|
ninetieth|one~hundredth;
```

Without the newlines. During decompression the `|`s are replaced with `'\0'` and the `~`s are replaced with `' '` (quirk of the way the characters are encoded into printable ASCII). These 'primitive' strings are then looked up by index in the `b` array using the `p` function and used to assemble the output.

Compression is a simple LZ like scheme where characters are either encoded as literals or as a negative offset into the buffer and a run length (encoded into two characters) if a match of length >=3 is found. The string could be compressed further using non-printable characters but I like my code to be copy and paste safe :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Hoj`, 98 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 12.25 bytes

```
ɾ₍∆ċ∆oƛ‛, j¡\.+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJIb2o9IiwiIiwiyb7igo3iiIbEi+KIhm/Gm+KAmywgasKhXFwuKyIsIiIsIiJd)

```
ɾ₍∆ċ∆oƛ‛, j¡\.+­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
ɾ                # ‎⁡H flag sets the stack to 100, so this makes a range [1,100]
 ₍               # ‎⁢Parallel apply the next two elements in a list
  ∆ċ∆o           # ‎⁣Nth Cardinal and Nth Ordinal (gotta love builtins)
      ƛ          # ‎⁤Map over the list of all cardinals and ordinals
       ‛, j      # ‎⁢⁡Join by the two character string ", " where the second character is a space
           ¡\.+  # ‎⁢⁢Convert to sentence case and add a period.
# ‎⁢⁣Implicit output, the j flag prints the top of the stack joined by newlines, which formats the list of two strings into the desired output.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Obviously non-competing.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 713

Similar to my [second PHP submission on this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55936/20666). (2444 - 713) / 2444 = 70.8% compression.

```
a=`Onez]cu^dP~Ntenz\`zHlvezmwgwjwkw{wqwpwHnQxZx]xcxux^xdxPx~xNmQXZX]XcXuX^XdXPX~XNforQbZb]bcbub^bdbPb~bNjQWZW]WcWuW^WdWPW~WNkQVZV]VcVuV^VdVPV~VN{QUZU]UcUuU^UdUPU~UNqQTZT]TcTuT^TdTPT~TNpQSZS]ScSuS^SdSPS~SNy.
FirstzaRMLKJI[ten}\`}Hlf}mGgGjGkG{GqGpGHnYx_xaxRxMxLxKxJxIx[mYX_XaXRXMXLXKXJXIX[forYb_babRbMbLbKbJbIb[jYW_WaWRWMWLWKWJWIW[kYV_VaVRVMVLVKVJVIV[{YU_UaURUMULUKUJUIU[qYT_TaTRTMTLTKTJTIT[pYS_SaSRSMSLSKSJSIS[yth.`,'eleven|`}|`z|twe|q}|{}|k}|j}|g}|pz|{z|kz|gz|one hundred|tyz|mdz|qtz|p~|q~|{~|k~|j~|m~|tie}|onez|nin}|twoz|fivez|firstz|teen|threez|secondz|for~|four|fif|twen~|six|thir|nine|eigh|, |seven|th, |ty-'.split('|').map((e,i)=>a=a.split('`GwHIJKLMNPduyQR~STUVWXYZ[]^_`cabgjxkmpqz{}~'[i]).join(e)),alert(a)
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45buvakf/)

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <s>415 391</s> 407

The cardinals are given by `IntegerName[n]`. The ordinals are derived from the cardinals.

```
s = StringRiffle; y = IntegerName; t = StringReplace;
k@n_ := If[(z = (TextWords["first second third a fifth a a a ninth,a, a twelfth a a a a a eighteenth a, twentieth"])[[n]]) == "a", y@n <> "th", z]
g@n_ := Module[{i = IntegerDigits[n], z}, z := y[Quotient[n, 10]*10];Which[n == 100, "one hundredth", n < 20, k[n], i[[-1]] == 0, t[z, "y" -> "ieth"], 3 > 2, z <> "-" <> k[i[[-1]]]]]
t[(s[y@Range@100 /. "one" -> "One", ", "] <> ".") <> s[g /@ Range@100 /. "first" -> "\nFirst", ", "] <> ".", "tt" -> "t"]
```

Output:

```
One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, nineteen, twenty, twenty-one, twenty-two, twenty-three, twenty-four, twenty-five, twenty-six, twenty-seven, twenty-eight, twenty-nine, thirty, thirty-one, thirty-two, thirty-three, thirty-four, thirty-five, thirty-six, thirty-seven, thirty-eight, thirty-nine, forty, forty-one, forty-two, forty-three, forty-four, forty-five, forty-six, forty-seven, forty-eight, forty-nine, fifty, fifty-one, fifty-two, fifty-three, fifty-four, fifty-five, fifty-six, fifty-seven, fifty-eight, fifty-nine, sixty, sixty-one, sixty-two, sixty-three, sixty-four, sixty-five, sixty-six, sixty-seven, sixty-eight, sixty-nine, seventy, seventy-one, seventy-two, seventy-three, seventy-four, seventy-five, seventy-six, seventy-seven, seventy-eight, seventy-nine, eighty, eighty-one, eighty-two, eighty-three, eighty-four, eighty-five, eighty-six, eighty-seven, eighty-eight, eighty-nine, ninety, ninety-one, ninety-two, ninety-three, ninety-four, ninety-five, ninety-six, ninety-seven, ninety-eight, ninety-nine, one hundred.
First, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth, eleventh, twelfth, thirteenth, fourteenth, fifteenth, sixteenth, seventeenth, eighteenth, nineteenth, twentieth, twenty-first, twenty-second, twenty-third, twenty-fourth, twenty-fifth, twenty-sixth, twenty-seventh, twenty-eighth, twenty-ninth, thirtieth, thirty-first, thirty-second, thirty-third, thirty-fourth, thirty-fifth, thirty-sixth, thirty-seventh, thirty-eighth, thirty-ninth, fortieth, forty-first, forty-second, forty-third, forty-fourth, forty-fifth, forty-sixth, forty-seventh, forty-eighth, forty-ninth, fiftieth, fifty-first, fifty-second, fifty-third, fifty-fourth, fifty-fifth, fifty-sixth, fifty-seventh, fifty-eighth, fifty-ninth, sixtieth, sixty-first, sixty-second, sixty-third, sixty-fourth, sixty-fifth, sixty-sixth, sixty-seventh, sixty-eighth, sixty-ninth, seventieth, seventy-first, seventy-second, seventy-third, seventy-fourth, seventy-fifth, seventy-sixth, seventy-seventh, seventy-eighth, seventy-ninth, eightieth, eighty-first, eighty-second, eighty-third, eighty-fourth, eighty-fifth, eighty-sixth, eighty-seventh, eighty-eighth, eighty-ninth, ninetieth, ninety-first, ninety-second, ninety-third, ninety-fourth, ninety-fifth, ninety-sixth, ninety-seventh, ninety-eighth, ninety-ninth, one hundredth.
```

Comment: Some uncorrect `eightth`

Comment: You were right!  I now corrected them.

Comment: You could change `"first" -> "\nFirst"` to `"fir" -> "\nFir"` to save 4 bytes.

Comment: @LegionMamal978, Good suggestion but it won't work because we are replacing elements (words) in a list: "first" is an element in the list, but "fir" is not.  If we try to implement your suggestion after the list of elements is `StringJoin`ed, then "twenty-first ...thirty-first..." will become "twenty-First...thirty-First...".

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 480

```js
/*TEST: redirect console output to snippet body */ console.log=x=>O.innerHTML=x

// Not a function, as a complete program is requested
b=x=>btoa(x).split`/`;
Z=i=>z[i]||z[i-8]||z[i-18];
y=b("ýø«²ßìyÊ'wûa·ýøÿÿÞ)ÿÿûpzWÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ");
z=b("þÞþÜ(þØkyïß¢êÿ~+ÞþÈ±þÇ¯zÞmþx§{û^÷¥z÷§þÜ÷¿¶«ÿ÷âÿÿz(!ÿûpzÿ~ÿÿÿÿ");
o=(z.map((v,i)=>i<20?i<13?v:(v||z[i-10])+'teen':z[S='slice'](0,10).map(d=>Z(i)+(d?'ty-'+d:'ty')))+`,${h='one hundred'}.\nF`).split`,`;
q=y.map((v,i)=>i<4?v:`${v||o[i]}th`);
q=z.map((v,i)=>i<20?' '+q[i]:q[S](0,10).map(d=>' '+Z(i)+(d?'ty-'+d:'tieth')));
console.log('O'+o.join`, `[S](3)+`${q}, ${h}th.`[S](4))

// INFO: z uncompressed is [,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thir,,fif,,,eigh,,twen,,for,,,,,]
// INCO: y uncompressed is [,first,second,third,,fif,,,eigh,nin,,,twelf,,,,,,,,,]
```

```css
#O { white-space: pre-wrap }
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - 842 bytes

Omitting regular PHP starting and ending tags, compression is 1 - 842/2445 = 65.6%

Basically getting the output of `base64_encode(gzdeflate($input, 9));` and reversing the operations. Obviously, if I chose to output in pure 8-bit vs. base-64, it would be 25% smaller, but at the risk of running into escape or non-printable characters.

```
echo gzinflate(base64_decode('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'));
```